# Custom module grid container will not show

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I know this question has been asked for so many times here on SO but nothing helped me to solve my issue.

I am trying to display a grid on my modules index page but it is not showing, I tried to `var_dump` `Mage::getModel('custombundle/bundle')->getCollection()` in a loop and it gave me output of data. Below is what I have coded so far:

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_CustomBundle>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </Company_CustomBundle>
    </modules>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <custombundle>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Company_CustomBundle</module>
                    <frontName>admin_custombundle</frontName>
                </args>
            </custombundle>
        </routers>
    </admin>

    <global>
        <helpers>
            <custombundle>
                <class>Company_CustomBundle_Helper</class>
            </custombundle>
        </helpers>

        <!-- Blocks -->
        <blocks>
            <company_custombundle>
                <class>Company_CustomBundle_Block</class>
            </company_custombundle>
        </blocks>

        <models>
            <custombundle>
                <class>Company_CustomBundle_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>custombundle_resource</resourceModel>
            </custombundle>
            <custombundle_resource>

                <class>Company_CustomBundle_Model_Resource</class>

                <entities>
                    <basket>
                        <table>custombundle_basket</table>
                    </basket>
                    <bundle>
                        <table>custombundle_bundle</table>
                    </bundle>
                </entities>

            </custombundle_resource>
        </models>

        <resources>

            <custombundle_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Company_CustomBundle</module>
                    <class>Company_CustomBundle_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
            </custombundle_setup>

            <custombundle_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </custombundle_write>

            <custombundle_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </custombundle_read>

        </resources>

    </global>

    <adminhtml>

        <!-- Layouts Configuration Starts -->
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <custombundle>
                    <file>custombundle.xml</file>
                </custombundle>
            </updates>
        </layout>
        <!-- !! Layouts Configuration -->

        <menu>
            <custombundle module="custombundle">
                <title>Custom Bundle</title>
                <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                <children>
                    <index module="custombundle">
                        <title>Custom Bundle</title>
                        <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                        <action>admin_custombundle/adminhtml_custombundle</action>
                    </index>

                    <other module="custombundle">
                        <title>Other</title>
                        <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                        <action>admin_custombundle/adminhtml_custombundle/other</action>
                    </other>
                </children>
            </custombundle>
        </menu>
    </adminhtml>

</config>
```

**app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/custombundle.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<layout version="0.1.0">

    <adminhtml_custombundle_index> <!-- custombundle controller index action -->
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="company_custombundle/adminhtml_custombundle_bundle" name="list_combination" />
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_custombundle_index>
</layout>
```

**controllers/Adminhtml/CustombundleController.php**

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $this->_title($this->__('Custom Bundle'))->_title($this->__('Category Combinations'))->loadLayout()->_setActiveMenu('custombundle/index');

    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

**Block/Adminhtml/Custombundle/Bundle.php**

```
class Company_CustomBundle_Block_Adminhtml_Custombundle_Bundle extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_custombundle';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'company_custombundle';
        $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('company_custombundle')->__('Custom Bundle Category combinations');
        $this->_addButtonLabel = Mage::helper('company_custombundle')->__('Add Item');
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

**Block/Adminhtml/Custombundle/Bundle/Grid.php**

```
class Company_CustomBundle_Block_Adminhtml_Custombundle_Bundle_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('bundleGrid');
        $this->setDefaultSort('bundle_id');
        $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
    }

    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getModel('custombundle/bundle')->getCollection();
        $this->setCollection($collection);

        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn('bundle_id', array(
                'header' => 'ID',
                'align' => 'right',
                'width' => '50px',
                'index' => 'bundle_id',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('assigned_category_id', array(
              'header' => 'Assigned with',
              'align' => 'left',
              'index' => 'assigned_category_id',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('category_id', array(
              'header' => 'Category',
              'align' => 'left',
              'index' => 'category_id',
        ));

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

    public function getRowUrl($row)
    {
         return $this->getUrl('*/*/edit', array('id' => $row->getId()));
    }
}
```

Comment: in "controllers/Adminhtml/CustombundleController.php" did you add the class declaration ?

Comment: yes it is there @dharth I have just put the `indexAction` there

Comment: ok, in your layout try to use "custombundle_adminhtml_custombundle_index" instead of "adminhtml_custombundle_index"

Comment: @dharth no it didn't work

Comment: Did you know if your block is called ? try to just echo something in the block constructor. If yes have you got an error message or just blank screen ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is answered properly on Magento stackexchange by [Rajeev](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/3535/rajeev-k-tomy) and [Jaimin](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/2443/jaimin-sutariya) you can check the answer as well as discussion [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/157682/38449). These guys really provided valuable inputs and suggested improvements that improved the quality of the code.

I will try to explain a bit about the corrections I made in my code that solved my issue.

**config.xml**

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <company_custombundle before="Mage_Adminhtml">Company_CustomBundle_Adminhtml</company_custombundle>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

In config.xml part I changed `router` part as `<use>admin</use>` is deprecated as of 1.9 version and had potential security threats as mentioned by [Mladen Ilić](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42004930/1929511).

Then accordingly corrected the menu part of the config.xml to support new routing as below:

```
<menu>
    <custombundle module="custombundle">
        <title>Custom Bundle</title>
        <sort_order>100</sort_order>
        <children>
            <index module="custombundle">
                <title>Custom Bundle</title>
                <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                <action>adminhtml/custombundle/index</action>
            </index>

            <other module="custombundle">
                <title>Other</title>
                <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                <action>adminhtml/custombundle/other</action>
            </other>
        </children>
    </custombundle>
</menu>
```

**Block/Adminhtml/Custombundle/Bundle.php**

```
class Company_CustomBundle_Block_Adminhtml_Custombundle_Bundle extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_custombundle_bundle';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'company_custombundle';
        $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('custombundle')->__('Custom Bundle Category combinations');
        $this->_addButtonLabel = Mage::helper('custombundle')->__('Add Item');
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Now here I changed `adminhtml_custombundle` to `adminhtml_custombundle_bundle` this change was done because if you look at `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Container::_prepareLayout()` method you will get to know that your container's child i.e `grid` or `Block/Adminhtml/Custombundle/Bundle/Grid.php` will never be called if you don't do this.

Another change in the above code was `Mage::Helper()` I changed its value from `company_custombundle` to `custombundle` only i.e without namespace.

After all I cleared magento's cache and reload... *Bingo the grid was showing there with data.

Answer (score 1):

Your admin route is not properly defined. You should never add new admin routes as it creates security issue and is highly discouraged.

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Company_CustomBundle after="Mage_Adminhtml">Company_CustomBundle_Adminhtml</Company_CustomBundle>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

More on admin route issue can be found here: https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-6788-technical-details

Best of luck

Comment: @Sagar Guhe: You are welcome. Don't forget to mark the correct answer. :)

Comment: answer was posted on this thread http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/157682/38449 yesterday and I have added same answer with little explanation here.